# Import file with two delimiter in SAS

Tags: import, sas, delimiter

I have a .scores file with two delimiters space and comma. I need to import it sas and not able to do it with regular import command. The format is as follows

832783_9399 973299,03200 238003

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use multiple delimiters in dlm  as show below

```
 data want;
 infile datalines dlm=' ,'  ;
 informat var1 var2 var3 var4 $60.;
input var1  $ var2 $ var3 $ var4 $;
datalines;
832783_9399 973299,03200 238003
;
```

Comment: Why is the `|` necessary here?

Comment: | is not needed and I have deleted it